# Passing variables from MEL to Expression MAYA

Tags: maya, mel

hie i have a slight confusion as to why what writing is not working.
in my MEL script editor I'm writing

```
string $Adistance = ("distanceDimensionShape1"+".distance");
expression -s (" $Bdistance = $Adistance; joint2.scaleX = $distance");
```

but I get this error

```
// Warning: line 1: Converting string "distanceDimensionShape1.distance" to a float value of 0. //
```

- I want joint2.scaleX to copy distanceDimensionShape1.distance float

Comment: SORRY wrote it incorrectly this is the real problem                                 float $distance = ("distanceDimensionShape1"+".distance");
expression -s (" $distance = $distance;");

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve with this expression and MEL script? It's hard to discern the solution with an expression that only sets a variable. And when you need to clarify the question, it often makes more sense to [edit] the question itself rather than cram the change in a comment.

Comment: I want joint2.scaleX to copy distanceDimensionShape1.distance float

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first I'm not a Mel programmer, I usually do my script in Python so there might be syntax errors in my code.

**Your problem:**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are trying to get the `distance` attribute of `distanceDimensionShape1` into a variable and set it to `scaleX` attribute from `joint2`.

**Your code:**

```
string $Adistance = ("distanceDimensionShape1"+".distance");
expression -s (" $Bdistance = $Adistance; joint2.scaleX = $distance");
```

*What you are doing in your 1st line:* You are declaring a string variable containing `"distanceDimensionShape1.distance"`, not getting the `distance` attribute of `distanceDimensionShape1`

*What you should be doing in your 1st line:* Use the [getAttr](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/getAttr.html) command provided in maya docs the retrieve the attribute of your shape.

*What you are doing in your second line:* You are trying to set `joint2.scaleX` which is a float value with a string value. I guess... because I don't know what's `$distance` as it appears only here in your code.

*What you should be doing in your second line:* Use [setAttr](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/setAttr.html) to properly set your attribute.

**My solution:**

I hope this will help as we have only few informations on your current problem:

```
float $Adistance = `getAttr distanceDimensionShape1.distance`;
setAttr joint2.scaleX  $Adistance;
```

1st line retrieves properly the selected attributes and storages it to a `float`.
2nd line set your attribute with the retrieved value.

**Note:**

- You can watch which methods are called when doing manipulation in maya by opening your script editor and checking `History > Echo All Commands`. This way you will be able to reproduce Maya's behaviour.
- Always have an internet browser pointing to Maya's Mel/Python doc
  when scripting: [link](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/)
- Try to develop more when posting a question on SO:

  1. What are your trying to achieve and how you plan to do it
  2. A commented block of code (approx 10-15 lines is fine and give a good overview of your mel script)
  3. What's your error message

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an expression once then change what connects to it, create it the following way:

```
expression -s ("joint2.scaleX = .I[0]")
```

Then you can connect a specific attribute to that plug like this:

```
connectAttr distanceDimensionShape1.distance expression1.input[0]
```

---

This is assuming there's a legitimate reason you couldn't just write the expression once directly:

```
expression -s ("joint2.scaleX = distanceDimensionShape1.distance")
```